# Как вытащить значение input type="range" и отправить на сервер

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2

`yii2`, с помощью `js` надо поменять значение поля формы `input type="range"` на другое (получаю от сервера запросом).

Когда я задаю ему значение (через `js`), после отправки на сервер оно почему-то теряется.

Вопрос: какой атрибут забирает php экшен и какой атрибут устанавливает js? Как вытащить тот атрибут, который забирает php?

поле формы:

```
<?= 
    $form->field($check, 'brightnessLevel')
         ->label('Яркость')
         ->input('range', [
             'id' => 'brightness',
             'value' => 0,
             'min' => -100,
             'max' => 100
    ])
?>
```

функция:

```
function setDefaultValue() {
    var xhmlhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhmlhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhmlhr.open('GET', '/url/url');
    xhmlhr.send();
    xhmlhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) 
            defalutVal = xhmlhr.responseText;
        brightness.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        brightness.value = defalutVal;
        changeBrightness();
    }
}
```

P.S. экшен:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $check = new EditingImage();
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($check->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
//            if ($model->save()){
//            }
//          здесь значение теряется (если не таскать сам ползунок, а именно через js пытаться устанавливать)
            $check->status = $check::STATUS_ON;
            $check->dir = Images::IMAGES_DIR;
            $check->url = $model->url;
            if ($check->increaseBrightness())
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'check' => $check,
        ]);
    }
```

pss

```
    console.log('defalutVal: ' + defalutVal);
    console.log('brightnessVal: ' + brightness.value);
    brightness.value = defalutVal;
    console.log('brightness.value = defalutVal (' + brightness.value + ')');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставьте `console.log(xhmlhr.responseText)` и посмотрите точно, что в ответе присылает сервер

Comment: @andreymal, посмотрел точно, приходит нужное значение.

Comment: А лучше всего написать фигурные скобки и ставить значение только после ответа от сервера.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, onreadystatechange - это разве не то? скобки для json? значение приходит, оно не устанавливается или теряется при подаче экшену. сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: onreadystatechange вызывается несколько раз с разными readyState. У вас в условии if только `defalutVal = xhmlhr.responseText;`, а вот остальной код не входит в if.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, да, не входит, так и было задумано. т.е. меняю значение я в любом случае. вот только на какое - на дефолтное в скрипте или на то, которое я получаю по запросу - зависит от ответа сервера.

Comment: Чего-то я не понимаю. Поставьте `console.log(defalutVal)` перед `brightness.value = defalutVal`. И расскажите нам, что происходит.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, выводит заданное по умолчанию значение

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Можно в виде скрина.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, добавил

Comment: Извините, но я хотел увидеть немного не то. Не нужно выводить значение `defaultVal`. Поставьте `console.log(defalutVal)` перед `brightness.value = defalutVal`. И покажите на скрине, что происходит.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, невнимательно прочитал, значение в js задается. поправил

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, все прекрасно передается, если я передаю это значение в качестве параметра или в теле в других запросах (там они немного другого вида). но формы yii2 из коробки почему то не видят это задаваемое js-ом значение

Comment: У вас то что на скрине, это все выводы в консоль? Сдается мне, вы или что-то обрезали на скрине или код в вопросе не актуальный. Потому что вот этот набор из `console.log('defalutVal: ' + defalutVal); ...` должен показаться как минимум 2 раза.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88446/discussion-between-dasauser-and-stepan-kasyanenko).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо было убрать эту строку:

```
    brightness.setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему не желаете пробовать с фигурными скобками как подсказал [@Stepan Kasyanenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933285/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-input-type-range#comment1547707_933285). Без них `JS` будет каждый раз выбрасывать исключение `defalutVal is not defined`, так как до ответа эта переменная не определена.

Проверьте, не отключен ли показ ошибок в консоли.

```js
let handler = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    defalutVal = this.responseText;
    brightness.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    brightness.value = defalutVal;
  }
  state.innerText = `readyState ${this.readyState}`
}

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => handler.call({
    readyState: i,
    status: i === 4 && 200,
    responseText: 50
  }), 500 * i);
}
```

```html
<div id="state">readyState</div>
<input id="brightness" type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0">
```

Comment: не, не то. я неправильно сфорумулировал вопрос, извините. поправил.

Comment: @dasauser а мне кажется что пытаетесь решить ещё одну проблему в том же вопросе, или код тоже сформулировали неправильно? ибо он принимает и устанавливает значение, о чём и был изначальный вопрос, а не отправляет.

Comment: Нет, все правильно. Экшен не забирает значение. В `$check->brightnessLevel`  пусто, однако если задавать значение не через js, а прямым вводом (перетаскивая ползунок инпута), то все работает, значение не передается. Очень похоже, что js устанавливает один атрибут, а php забирает другой. Значит мне нужно не value, а другой атрибут, который я , как раз таки, не знаю как вытащить с инпута.